# 1-periodic and continuous is uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $f$ be a $1$-periodic function that is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. Then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

Indeed, since $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, it is continuous in $[0,1]$ which is compact; therefore $f$ is uniformly continuous there, that is, for $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta(\varepsilon)>0$ such that for all $x,y \in [0,1]$ $|x-y|<\delta\implies|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$. Now, let $x,y$ be two points of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $|x-y|<\delta(\varepsilon/2)$. We distinguish two cases:

Case 1: there exists an integer $n$ between $x,y$. Then without loss of generality, we may assume that $x<1<y$, since $f$ is periodic. if $y=1+t$, we have $|f(x)-f(y)|=|f(x)-f(1+t)|=|f(x)-f(t)|\leq|f(x)-f(1)|+|f(1)-f(t)|=$ $=|f(x)-f(1)|+|f(0)-f(t)|<\varepsilon$ , because $|1-y|<\delta(\varepsilon/2)$ hence $|t|<\delta(\varepsilon/2)$ and $|1-x|<\delta(\varepsilon/2)$ too.

Case 2: there is no integer between $x,y$. Then without loss of generality (periodicity) we may assume that $x,y\in (0,1)$ and we have nothing to prove.

Any objections?

Comment: Looks good. If you care for an alternative presentation, in the past I have written this by using $[0,2]$ instead of $[0,1]$. Then one doesn't need to worry about cases. For every epsilon choose delta as in the uniform continuity condition (which can be chosen with the extra condition that $\delta <1$). Then $x,y$ have representatives in $[0,2]$ and therefore, the uniform continuity holds for $f$. You save in not having to consider cases and not having to use a the triangle inequality.

Comment: Haha, smart trick! thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks fine, but in case 2 you should have written $[0,1]$ instead of $(0,1)$.

Comment: Depending on how you interpret "no integer in between", then their Case 2 doesn't need the boundary points in $[0,1]$. That case would have been treated in their Case 1.